# Why Open Sans fonts seems to be corrupted when using for select box as font face in chrome and opera?

Tags: css, google-chrome, fonts, font-face, opera

**HTML**

```
<select multiple="multiple">
    <option>Option-1</option>
    <option>Option-2</option>
    <option>Option-3</option>
    <option>Option-4</option>
    <option>Option-5</option>
</select>
```

**CSS**

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'OpenSansRegular';
    src: url('OpenSans-Regular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('OpenSans-Regular-webfont.svg#open_sansregular') format('svg'),
    url('OpenSans-Regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('OpenSans-Regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
    url('OpenSans-Regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}

select {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin: 20px;
    font-family: 'OpenSansRegular',Arial,sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

I use OpenSans font as font-face with using fontsquirrel webfontkit tool. Everything seems normal for ff,ie,safari but when open page in chrome or opera, it seems as below image;
[image]

My code as above. Why fonts seems to be corrupted for chrome and opera?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try to change the order of loaded source files?
Like putting the svg at the bottom of the list.

Maybe he's trying to render the svg inside of the select boxes and messing up there.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'OpenSansRegular';
    src: url('OpenSans-Regular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('OpenSans-Regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('OpenSans-Regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
    url('OpenSans-Regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('OpenSans-Regular-webfont.svg#open_sansregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: it solves the problem. But now other fonts expect selectbox not display correctly. So I define one more font as OpenSansRegularFix for overcome this problem. Thank you @tysk

Comment: @midstack well I think the matter is how your browser is now rendering the other font-files. Maybe you should try to avoid svg because it's the most different rendered fonttype.